# sshd_config AllowUsers and IPv6

Tags: ssh, authentication, ipv6, reverse-dns

Have two servers communicating via ssh and crontab, a "master" and a "slave". Only the master can connect (execute command) on the slave.

Authentication *was* done automatically (IPv4) thanks to

- master's `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` added to slave's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- slave's `sshd_config` having `AllowUsers me@1.2.3.4`

It was working fine until IPv6 was added

- both master and slave have IPv6 enabled
- both servers have had DNS reverse setup for both protocols
- sshd_config changed to `AllowUsers me@myhost.tld`

and was hoping `sshd` slave does a reverse lookup of the incoming IPv6 IP (to get `myhost.tld`) but `auth.log` shows

> `User me from 2103:cc11::...:fe93:4a10 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers`

I'd have two questions

1. does `sshd` perform an IPv6 reverse lookup to find out if the host matches? (if yes, there is another problem)
2. <s>what is the correct way to add an IPv6 address hard-coded in `AllowUsers`? It seems `me@[2103:cc11::...:fe93:4a10]` doesn't work</s>. (*edit* works without the `[]`)

Comment: @anx Actually the servers have other ways to be accessed for maintenance, and if DNS resolution is down from these machines POV we'll have more problems than that, but that's a good point. And incidentally came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149540/host-is-able-to-resolve-a-hostname-ssh-isnt) and nsswitch's `mdns4_minimal` could be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the UseDNS directive.

> "**UseDNS**  Specifies whether sshd(8) should look up the remote host name, and to check that the resolved hostname for the remote IP address maps back to the very same IP address.
>
> If this option is set to no (the default) then only addresses and not host names may be used in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys from and sshd_config Match Host directives."

As a side-note you could always configure the client to force IPv4 for connection to that particular host in your ssh_config. I mostly used AllowUsers to match usernames, if you want to match on hostnames and IP you might want to have a look at using TCP wrapper instead.

See: https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_tcp_wrapper.html